# Computational method 2nd order differential equations : 2 conditions at two boundaries

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

I have the following system of second order differential equation :

$\left\{ \begin{split} &\frac{dy}{dt}=F(t,x,y) \\ 
&\frac{dx}{dt}=y  
\end{split}
\right.$

with $y(t)$ and $x(t)$ defined in the interval : $I=[0,1]$.
I would have liked just to compute : 
$\left\{ \begin{split} &y_{k+1}=y_k+ F(t_k,x_k,y_k)\Delta t \\ 
&x_{k+1}=x_k + y_k \Delta t
\end{split}
\right.$

But I have two boundary conditions defined at different points, so that I have no point to start with :

$\left\{ \begin{split} &y(0)=0 \\ 
&x(1)=x_0
\end{split}
\right.$

How could I proceed, with that method or another one  ?

Comment: Have you tried the shooting method? Here is a wiki link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method

Comment: Thx ! Do u know about other methods ?

Comment: Since this is a boundary value problem for a second order ODE, i.e. $x''(t)=F(t, x(t), x'(t))$, there are some other methods, which might work. There are for example the finite element method,  the Galerkin approximation or the shooting method with other Runge-Kutta schemes. Furthermore if your equation has additional structure you might be able to implement some other methods. For example if your equation is the Euler-Lagrange equation of a Functional, i.e. has variationell structure, then you could implement a gradient search method to find an extremum.